# How to increase the default 5 sec wait period with 100millisecond polling interval, in Serenity

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

My test is failing with "No such element exception: Expected condition failed: waiting for By.cssSelector: #icon to be displayed (tried for 5 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)".

How do i increase the polling interval?is there a way to override this value?

I have tried using waitUntilVisible().setImplicitTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(40));. But it didn't work.

```
ICON.resolveFor(actor).waitUntilVisible();
actor.attemptsTo(Click.on(LOGIN_LINK));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_working_with_timeouts) you can use following method :

```
setImplicitTimeout(5, SECONDS);
```

and for resetting the global timeout :

```
resetImplicitTimeout();
```